# Retrieve smart card's PAN with Python and pyscard

Tags: python, apdu, pan, pyscard

I'm trying to retrieve the PAN of a smart card using `pyscard` in `Python`. What I have done so far is to connect to the reader and to retrieve various information about the reader and the card... but I cannot find the way to get the serial number...

Using pyscard, the first thing to do is to create a communication `context` between PC and Smart Card:

```
hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
```

Once the context has been established, let's try to get the list of active smart card readers:

```
hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
```

`readers` is a list, readers[0] will contain the reader, should you possess only one. At this point, what I did is to get the `ATR` of the card:

```
hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(hcontext,
current_reader, SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)
```

And it works. Then I tried to communicate with the card: here I write the way to get a random number, using the APDU command and the 0x84 hex in the second position (INS).

```
hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
```

As you can see an APDU is composed by 5 different hex digits: CLA, INS, P1, P2, P3.

Ok, still not serial number, but I'm fighting at least :-)

By the way, [I'm reading the pyscard documentation](https://pyscard.sourceforge.io/epydoc/index.html) and the [ISO7816 doc](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_12).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify *which* smartcard you are using.

If I am remembering right, not all the cards had the serial number accessible and if it is accessible, I don't think there is a standard command.

Anyway, you should take a look at the iso 7816-4 standand, which defines the APDU commands. Additionally, you should check the documentation of your card to see if it has some non-standard APDU command that can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will update this question when I'll discover something new. A the moment I have been able to receive the ATR. My users do not have all the same type of smart card, so I was looking for a general way to get the serial number (at least I know that every card they possess has a serial number). Pyscard has *many* different commands and I am exploring them...

Comment: Ok, one step forward: I realize that I can send APDU commands to the smart card. Now I am looking for the mysterious command which will return the serial number... Thanks for mentioning ISO 7816-4.